# Python, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1). How to troubleshoot?

Tags: python, json, api, blockchain

New to python and programming in general here, go easy on me lol.

I have a script that polls a blockchain API every 60 seconds to get updated data from the JSON API. It polls the latest activity then prints out the new activity with updated numbers for the hotspots.

For the past 3-4 weeks it's been working flawlessly.  It was only the last 3-4 days or so that I started to get this error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hello\Desktop\Dev\scripts\script-polling1.py", line 77, in <module>
    data2 = res1.json()['data']
  File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads        
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode        
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode    
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Whenever it errors out, I just restart it and it will work for another 1-4 hours then crash again.

The error above shows it stopped at line 77 which is where I have my json() call to the API, but it's not always consistent as I have multiple calls to different json() api URLs. It varies between json()'s when it errors.

But for the sake of troubleshooting, this is the json() for line 77 above.

```
for hotspotaddress in data:
    foundaddress = hotspotaddress['address']
    foundname = hotspotaddress['name']
    res1 = requests.get('https://api.url/' + foundaddress + '/activity/count?min_time=-1%20day&bucket=day')
    data2 = res1.json()['data']   ##THIS IS LINE 77 where the script crashes##
    previous_witness = str(data2['poc_receipts_v1'])
    previous_rewards = str(data2['rewards_v2'])
    previous_info.append([foundaddress,foundname,previous_witness,previous_rewards])
```

This is a small sample of the json it pulls from

```
{
  "data": {
    "vars_v1": 0,
    "validator_heartbeat_v1": 0,
    "unstake_validator_v1": 0,
    "transfer_validator_stake_v1": 0,
    "transfer_hotspot_v1": 0,
a lot more inbetween.
    "assert_location_v2": 1,
    "assert_location_v1": 0,
    "add_gateway_v1": 1
  }
}
```

Now I'm guessing it must be something in the API data since the script 'does' work, and it must crash once it has data it doesn't recognized or something.

I guess my question is how do I even troubleshoot this since the blockchain API data is consistently changing as every second/minute goes.  Read dozens of other stackoverflow articles with the same topic but can't figure out if any of them apply to my issue.  Am I using json() wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated for this newbie!

Comment: you could wrap your json code calls in a try except block. Catch the json parsing error and print/log the data you were trying to parse so you can inspect it to see what was wrong. I would also suggest that you check that the request.get call was succuessful, maybe your getting a 5xx or a 4xx error

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I'll look into catching the the error and printing the log when it happens.  I'll have to figure out how to parse the json error lol. 

what's weird is that I had the script running from a command prompt and another from my visual studio code, and only the command prompt failed at the time vs both.  Sometimes it's the other way around.

Comment: I suspect that on the case where it fails you will be getting some http error thats not a 2xx response so you end up not having data that is actual json so the parser fails

Comment: Hi Chris.  That makes sense.  Part of the error above is "JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None", which I guess it's erroring out when there is no value returned, but runs normally if something is returned.  I guess I may need to review the code to have an if/else in case there is any items that return as nothing

Answer (score 0):

So while this may not be a full answer since i cannot tell you why you may be having the error I would suggest to add the following to your code to help debug the issue

```py
for hotspotaddress in data:
    foundaddress = hotspotaddress['address']
    foundname = hotspotaddress['name']
    res1 = requests.get('https://api.url/' + foundaddress + '/activity/count?min_time=-1%20day&bucket=day')
    try
        data2 = res1.json()['data']  ##THIS IS LINE 77 where the script crashes##
        previous_witness = str(data2['poc_receipts_v1'])
        previous_rewards = str(data2['rewards_v2'])
        previous_info.append([foundaddress, foundname, previous_witness, previous_rewards])
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as jd:
        print("http response code: ", res1.status_code)
        print("http response data: ", res1.content)
        raise  jd
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I'll add these lines to my code where they're failing at the json() and see if anything comes up.

Comment: Keep us posted. Like i said not a full answer but not exactly a comment either.